# Batch file doesn't run properly when called within SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I'm having a strange issue where a batch file doesn't fully work if called from a stored procedure but if it is ran manually it all works fine.

The batch file just creates a few directories then sets the permissions like so:

```
md "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Material"
md "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Costs"
md "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project"

icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Material" /inheritance:r
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Material" /grant "SYSTEM":F
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Material" /grant "DOMAIN\Domain Admins":(CI)(OI)M
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Material" /grant "DOMAIN\SG_Material":(CI)(OI)M

icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Costs" /inheritance:r
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Costs" /grant "SYSTEM":F
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Costs" /grant "DOMAIN\Domain Admins":(CI)(OI)M
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Costs" /grant "DOMAIN\SG_Costs":(CI)(OI)M 

icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /inheritance:r
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /grant "SYSTEM":F
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /grant "DOMAIN\Domain Admins":(CI)(OI)M
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /grant "DOMAIN\SG_Project":(CI)(OI)M
```

The below stored procedure in SQL passes 'foldernumber' to the batch file (%1)

```
 DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @CMDSQL = 'C:\CreateFolders.bat ' + @foldernumber
    EXEC master..xp_CMDShell @CMDSQL
```

Running "CreateFolders.bat 1125" correctly creates a folder named 1125, creates the sub folders (Material, Costs, Project) and sets the permissions which is all good.

If SQL then kicks of the stored procedure, the batch file runs, creates the 'variable' folder and it's subfolder but **doesn't** apply the permissions.

A few things worth mentioning:

- I've given the SQL server object Full Control on \\SERVER\Share (both share and NTFS levels)
- The batch file is local to the SQL server

It feels like the stored procedure isn't running with high enough privileges but I'm not sure how to go about changing that - if at all possible.

Comment: How did you determine the "SQL Server object"?

Comment: Did you consider capturing standard error to a log file so that you might see what problems there might be?

Comment: @WolfgangK It's the computer object in AD

Comment: @Squashman I did try but my batch knowledge isn't the best, however I noticed when you run a stored procedure manually which is calling a batch file it shows you the output which led me to the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.

I changed the batch file to remove inheritance and grant SYSTEM permissions on one line.

So from this:

```
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /inheritance:r
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /grant "SYSTEM":F
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /grant "DOMAIN\Domain Admins":(CI)(OI)M
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /grant "DOMAIN\SG_Project":(CI)(OI)M
```

To this:

```
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /inheritance:r /grant "SYSTEM":F
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /grant "DOMAIN\Domain Admins":(CI)(OI)M
icacls  "\\SERVER\Share\Job\%1\Project" /grant "DOMAIN\SG_Project":(CI)(OI)M
```

Not 100% sure why it works but it does!